# Intent failed with Canceled on SpeechFactory.fromSubscription (LUIS azure, android sdk)

Tags: android, azure, websocket, speech-recognition, azure-language-understanding

I am getting the following message when trying to analyze an utterance with LUIS using the cognitive service android SDK:

***Final result received: Intent failed with Canceled. Did you enter your Language Understanding subscription? WebSocket Upgrade failed with an authentication error (403). Please check the subscription key or the authorization token, and the region name., intent:***

I am able to get an utterance evaluation via REST using the same Subscription key , and App ID passed to the SpeechFactory methods.

Moreover, continuous recognition through the Android SDK works as well.

Anyone is getting my same issue ?

source available at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/java/android/sdkdemo/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/cognitiveservices/speech/samples/sdkdemo/MainActivity.java .

Code here:

```
 recognizeIntentButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        final String logTag = "intent";
        final ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<>();

        disableButtons();
        clearTextBox();

        content.add("");
        content.add("");
        try {
            final SpeechFactory intentFactory = SpeechFactory.fromSubscription(LanguageUnderstandingSubscriptionKey, LanguageUnderstandingServiceRegion);
            final IntentRecognizer reco = intentFactory.createIntentRecognizerWithStream(createMicrophoneStream());

            LanguageUnderstandingModel intentModel = LanguageUnderstandingModel.fromAppId(LanguageUnderstandingAppId);
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : intentIdMap.entrySet()) {
                reco.addIntent(entry.getKey(), intentModel, entry.getValue());
            }

            reco.IntermediateResultReceived.addEventListener((o, intentRecognitionResultEventArgs) -> {
                final String s = intentRecognitionResultEventArgs.getResult().getText();
                Log.i(logTag, "Intermediate result received: " + s);
                content.set(0, s);
                setRecognizedText(TextUtils.join(System.lineSeparator(), content));
            });

            final Future<IntentRecognitionResult> task = reco.recognizeAsync();
            setOnTaskCompletedListener(task, result -> {
                Log.i(logTag, "Continuous recognition stopped.");
                String s = result.getText();

                if (result.getReason() != RecognitionStatus.Recognized) {
                    s = "Intent failed with " + result.getReason() + ". Did you enter your Language Understanding subscription?" + System.lineSeparator() + result.getErrorDetails();
                }

                String intentId = result.getIntentId();
                String intent = "";
                if (intentIdMap.containsKey(intentId)) {
                    intent = intentIdMap.get(intentId);
                }
                Log.i(logTag, "Final result received: " + s + ", intent: " + intent);
                content.set(0, s);
                content.set(1, " [intent: " + intent + "]");
                setRecognizedText(TextUtils.join(System.lineSeparator(), content));
                enableButtons();
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            displayException(ex);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error with the example available here:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/java/android/sdkdemo

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: I'd like more information about your specific conditions. How are you running this code? Are you testing using a virtual device? Any specific platform?

Comment: I've tested it on virtual emulator and physical device as well (android 6.0 and 8).